# Problem with loading .gltf files in Github pages of my React Three.js app with Vite

Tags: javascript, reactjs, deployment, three.js, vite

I deployed my React Three.js with Vite app in Github pages, and I can't get it running on a live server - https://thehero9.github.io/ThreeJsReactFiber/

This here is the code in my repo - https://github.com/TheHero9/ThreeJsReactFiber
I have no trouble with the app locally, you can try cloning it with git, then run:

```
npm install
npm run dev
```

In order to check how it works locally.

I think the .gltf files are not being loaded correctly due to a problem with the file paths or the loading code. Please, can you help us and check whether you can find why the .gltf files are not loading?

Errors:

[image: Errors 1]

[image]

Everything is loaded properly on a local server:
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xV31l.jpg

Comment: You have a `public` folder that you totally ignored - it's where all of the assets that you load in runtime should be

Comment: See your `gh-pages` branch https://github.com/TheHero9/ThreeJsReactFiber/tree/gh-pages